# Sitecore 9 Geo IP service error constructor not found

Tags: geo-location

I am using Sitecore (9.0 update 2) Geo IP service. For that I have installed Sitecore IP Geolocation Service Client 1.2 package from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_IP_Geolocation_Service_Client/12/Sitecore_IP_Geolocation_Service_Client_12_for_Sitecore_XP_80.aspx

I have downloaded TestIpPage from https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498 solution 3 section. When I am testing the http://local.sitecoredemo/sitecore/TestIp.aspx page and clicked on GetInformationByIp.

I am getting the following error: `Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider. No matching constructor was found.`

Below is the screenshot of the error
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You installed a module for Sitecore 8 on a Sitecore 9 site. From Sitecore 8.1 and higher, you don't need that module - it's already included.

Check the documentation on https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/ip_geolocation/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation but be sure to read it for your Sitecore version. Latest update is for 9.0.1 which should be ok for you.

> Sitecore IP Geolocation is included in the initial version of Sitecore
>   Experience Platform 8.1 (Sitecore XP) and all later versions by
>   default, it is also tested with all subsequent updates. This means you
>   only need to subscribe to the Sitecore IP Geolocation service.

Comment: I have removed the module but still getting the same error when i access that page.Should i install sitecore Geo IP service from app center?One of my colleague said,updating licence with Geo Ip services should fix it without installing Geo IP services.We updates licence but still getting same error.Remember i have not installed GeoIP services from app module as it is asking me to enter user name and password which i do not have.

Comment: Start by checking your filesystem. Compare the bin (and if needed config) folder with a clean Sitecore 9.0.1 to make sure the files match.

Comment: The module was probably not removed correctly. If the config files from it are still present, the error will remain.